# Understanding escaping closures Swift

Tags: ios, swift, escaping, closures

Need help with escaping closures.

I understand that the definition of escaping closures is  `If a closure is passed as an argument to a function and it is invoked after the function returns, the closure is escaping.`

I believe there are a few scenarios where escaping closures are necessary.

1. Setting an outside variable as the passing closure

   I understand this because the variable lives even after the function returns.
2. Asynchronous operations

   Things like `Dispatch.main.async{}` or `Network Request`.This is the part the I don't quite understand. I understand that `Dispatch.main.async{}` runs on a different thread and that async operations take a while to complete hence the name async. However, I cannot understand how these operations outlive the scope of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `DispatchQueue.main.async{}` you are creating a closure (a `block` in Objective-C) that is sent to the given dispatch queue.  Your function will then continue running after the `async` call and could end before the block has a chance to run on the `DispatchQueue`.  The closure has "escaped"!

The code in the block will actually be run when the block reaches the front of its `DispatchQueue`

The `async` doesn't mean that the operation will take a long time, it means that this function (the one calling `async`) will not pause to wait on the block to complete.

(if you DID want to pause and wait for the operation to complete, you could call `sync` instead of `async`).

Comment: Hi Scott! Just to clarify the "escaping part". My understanding of async is that the operations after async operations will continue without waiting for the async operations to end. So in this context, the async "lives outside" the function since it is sent to a different "place" to run while the following part of the function continues to run?

Comment: Yes.  The "different place" the block you pass to `async` is  sent to is the `DispatchQueue`.  Anything that follows the call to `async` in the function will continue to run.  The closure has therefore "escaped" the context of the function's body.

Answer (score 0):

When you do *asynchronous* work it might *escape* the current scope cause, by definition, it won't be waited for its *completion*.
This is also why the terminology *completion* is used for those *closures* adopted in *asynchronous* code for the delivery of results.

Here's an example, assuming `queue` is a `DispatchQueue` and `someHugeWork() -> R` is a *synchronous* function which returns a result `R`:

```
func doItSync() -> R {
    var result: R!
    queue.sync {
       result = someHugeWork()
    }
    // the function has to wait for the code submitted synchronously 
    // on the queue.
    
    return result
}

func doItAsync(completion: @escaping (R) -> Void) {
   queue.async {
     let result = someHugeWork()
     completion(result)
   }
   // work was submitted asynchronously on the queue, hence the function 
   // just returns, therefore the completion closure might escape this
   // scope.
}
```

Now, obviously in this case `doItSync()` does not really make sense, since it'll block the current thread until `someHugeWork()` has executed on a different queue. That is also why you can return the result from its scope: it waits for it. I've only added this to let you see the difference between *synchronous* code and *asynchronous* code for returning a result.

On the other hand `doItAsync(completion:)` just returns immediately without having to wait for `someHugeWork()` to complete on a different queue, hence it won't block the current thread.
Since you've submitted this work *asynchronously* on the queue you now have no control about when it will be executed and that is also why your only way to return the result from `someHugeWork()` is by using a *completion* closure, which has to be *captured* inside the *work item* submitted *asynchronously*… If you think about it for a moment it'll be as if such *completion* closure is stored to be retrieved by the queue at a later time when it will executes the work item submitted *asynchronously* (you said in your question that you did got the concept of storing a closure).

Now let's also see a method which doesn't need an *escaping* closure, that'll be the `body` parameter of `Sequence`'s `forEach(_:)` method: this method executes the given closure on every element of the sequence, that'll be as in doing:

```
func forEach(_ body: (Element) -> Void) {
   for element in self {
      body(element)
   }
   // the function returns only after the for-in loop has completed,
   // hence body closure only executes in the scope of this method,
   // thus it never escapes.
}
```

(for the sake of simplicity I've omitted the throwing annotations)

In this case the `body` closure never escapes `forEach(_:)` method's scope, therefore it doesn't need to be annotated as `@escaping`: it will only executes inside the for-in loop which has to complete before the method can return.